# MVVM - how to treat multiple core objects?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm

We're writing an application from scratch (core & app, the app is MVVM). The core contains a Test object, that is composed of blocks. We have about 30 different kinds of blocks. They are implemented as a composite pattern - we have an abstract block, and leaf & composite blocks that inherit from it. All other kinds of blocks inherit from either leaf (like a 'print' block) or composite (like a 'for' block).
My question is about the connection core-application: The application needs to present the tree-like structure of the test. For this, it should know what parameters the block has and how to present them (it can be 1 string parameter, 3 int, 1 string and 1 int that can have only 3 values etc.), and whether or not the block has children. Some other requirements might come along later.

It seems easiest to expose all our concrete blocks in our API, wrap each in its own block in the model and then use data templates to bind the different properties to the fields. Problem is, we don't want to expose our core internal to the application this way.

Another option is to expose only the abstract block and add an entity to the API - Presentable Block, that will hold it and also hold a general representation of its parameters (let's say, a list of Parameter objects, each such objects holds the needed information). In this case, the app will have to parse such a list for each block, and we're unsure about the usage of data templates - is it even possible?

I'll appreciate your comments on the 2 suggestions plus of course new ideas.
Thanks.